# Gradle artifactory plugin cannot resolve dependency on configuration phase

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I am trying to resolve dependency in configuration phase with artifactory gradle plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'

artifactory {
  contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
  ...
  resolve {
    repository {
      repoKey = 'repo'
      username = "${artifactory_user}"
      password = "${artifactory_password}"
      maven = true
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:+'
}

task testCustomResolve {
  logger.quiet configurations.getByName('compile').singleFile.absolutePath
}
```

And it gives me

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
>   Cannot resolve external dependency commons-lang:commons-lang:+ because no repositories are defined.

It works as a charm in execution phase

```
task testCustomResolve << {
  logger.quiet configurations.getByName('compile').singleFile.absolutePath
}
```

or when I use mavenCentral()

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Try placing your task definition inside an `afterEvaluate {...}` block.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm getting the same error. In my case, it seems to work fine when I run the actual build, but I get the error when trying to list all tasks...

Comment: Also getting the same error. Quite frustrating...

Comment: Might help someone in future - A repository definition needs to be added outside of buildscript block ex.  repositories {  mavenCentral()   }

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't need to publish to Artifactory, I noticed that it works better if you don't use the `artifactory {}` syntax. Instead, try using:

```
plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.4.10"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/${artifactory_repo}"
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: After I upgraded IntelliJ IDEA to 2019.2, `artifactory {}` syntax stopped working probably due to a newly introduced bug. But `maven {}` syntax still works, so i migrated my build.gradle to use maven syntax.